# Which removal tool for Rotor PF4624

Tags: bottom-bracket, rotor

I have the Rotor PF4624 386 Road Bottom Bracket (C04-026-01010-0) in my Open U.P. Frame (BB386EVO pressfit 86.5x46mm BB shell) and need to remove it to install a Di2. I have read that some people pressed out the bearings only and ran in some trouble afterwards since they used the wrong removing tool. So I want to be on the save side from the start but do not know which removal tool I should use.

Can anyome help me here?

There is a side question on this. Is it possible to install the old bottom bracket or is that not recommandable?

Comment: My instinct would be to contact Rotor customer support with this question. You want a tool that will engage the cups rather than the bearings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Your options can be summarised as tools that push, or tools that pull.

A normal bearing puller can be difficult to use without damaging the paint on the bottom bracket shell.

Park offers this tool for use with BBs that have a 22-24mm shaft diameter:
https://www.parktool.com/product/press-fit-bottom-bracket-bearing-tool-set-bbt-90-3
Other brands may have similar products.

I don't have any bikes with pushfit BBs so I can't comment on reusing a BB removed with such a tool.

Comment: I think that generally, plastic BB cups are most likely going to get deformed when pressed out (unless they were loose in the frame cups to begin with, in which case you have bigger problems). Metal BBs should be OK if pressed out carefully.